# Default Constructor never called

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, twitter-oauth

I'm working with a oAuthTwitterTimeline example that Andy created but I'm kind of having a hard time making sure the default constructor is called(Parameterless Constructor) to pull the data from my web.config file instead of having me hardcode the app settings in.

I am calling the method "GetMyTimeline()" but AuthenticateSettings.

I get a bunch of null reference exceptions when I finally jump into AuthenticateMe method.

```
AuthResponse twitAuthResponse = authenticate.AuthenticateMe(AuthenticateSettings);
```

This is the parameterless constructor

```
public OAuthTwitterWrapper()
    {
        string oAuthConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oAuthConsumerKey"];
        string oAuthConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oAuthConsumerSecret"];
        string oAuthUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oAuthUrl"];

        AuthenticateSettings = new AuthenticateSettings { OAuthConsumerKey = oAuthConsumerKey, OAuthConsumerSecret = oAuthConsumerSecret, OAuthUrl = oAuthUrl };

        string screenname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["screenname"];
        string include_rts = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["include_rts"];
        string exclude_replies = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exclude_replies"];
        int count = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["count"]);
        string timelineFormat = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["timelineFormat"];         
        TimeLineSettings = new TimeLineSettings
        {
            ScreenName = screenname,
            IncludeRts = include_rts,
            ExcludeReplies = exclude_replies,
            Count = count,
            TimelineFormat = timelineFormat
        };
        string searchFormat = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["searchFormat"];
        string searchQuery = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["searchQuery"];
        SearchSettings = new SearchSettings
        {
            SearchFormat = searchFormat,
            SearchQuery = searchQuery
        };

    }
```

Nothing special in the controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly OAuthTwitterWrapper.OAuthTwitterWrapper _oAuthTwitterWrapper;

    public HomeController(OAuthTwitterWrapper.OAuthTwitterWrapper oAuthTwitterWrapper)
    {
        _oAuthTwitterWrapper = oAuthTwitterWrapper;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetTwitterFeed()
    {
        return Json(_oAuthTwitterWrapper.GetMyTimeline(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

//Some more stuff
}
```

The whole class "OAuthTwitterWrapper"

```
namespace OAuthTwitterWrapper
{
public class OAuthTwitterWrapper : IOAuthTwitterWrapper
{
    public IAuthenticateSettings AuthenticateSettings { get; set; }
    public ITimeLineSettings TimeLineSettings { get; set; }
    public ISearchSettings SearchSettings { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The default constructor takes all the settings from the appsettings file
    /// </summary>
    public OAuthTwitterWrapper()
    {
        string oAuthConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oAuthConsumerKey"];
        string oAuthConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oAuthConsumerSecret"];
        string oAuthUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oAuthUrl"];
        AuthenticateSettings = new AuthenticateSettings { OAuthConsumerKey = oAuthConsumerKey, OAuthConsumerSecret = oAuthConsumerSecret, OAuthUrl = oAuthUrl };
        string screenname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["screenname"];
        string include_rts = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["include_rts"];
        string exclude_replies = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exclude_replies"];
        int count = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["count"]);
        string timelineFormat = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["timelineFormat"];         
        TimeLineSettings = new TimeLineSettings
        {
            ScreenName = screenname,
            IncludeRts = include_rts,
            ExcludeReplies = exclude_replies,
            Count = count,
            TimelineFormat = timelineFormat
        };
        string searchFormat = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["searchFormat"];
        string searchQuery = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["searchQuery"];
        SearchSettings = new SearchSettings
        {
            SearchFormat = searchFormat,
            SearchQuery = searchQuery
        };

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This allows the authentications settings to be passed in
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="authenticateSettings"></param>
    public OAuthTwitterWrapper(IAuthenticateSettings authenticateSettings)
    {
        AuthenticateSettings = authenticateSettings;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This allows the authentications and timeline settings to be passed in
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="authenticateSettings"></param>
    /// <param name="timeLineSettings"></param>
    public OAuthTwitterWrapper(IAuthenticateSettings authenticateSettings, ITimeLineSettings timeLineSettings)
    {
        AuthenticateSettings = authenticateSettings;
        TimeLineSettings = timeLineSettings;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This allows the authentications, timeline and search settings to be passed in
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="authenticateSettings"></param>
    /// <param name="timeLineSettings"></param>
    /// <param name="searchSettings"></param>
    public OAuthTwitterWrapper(IAuthenticateSettings authenticateSettings, ITimeLineSettings timeLineSettings, ISearchSettings searchSettings)
    {
        AuthenticateSettings = authenticateSettings;
        TimeLineSettings = timeLineSettings;
        SearchSettings = searchSettings;
    }

    public string GetMyTimeline()
    {
        var timeLineJson = string.Empty;
        IAuthenticate authenticate = new Authenticate();
        AuthResponse twitAuthResponse = authenticate.AuthenticateMe(AuthenticateSettings);

        // Do the timeline
        var utility = new Utility();
        timeLineJson = utility.RequstJson(TimeLineSettings.TimelineUrl, twitAuthResponse.TokenType, twitAuthResponse.AccessToken);

        return timeLineJson;
    }

    public string GetSearch()
    {
        var searchJson = string.Empty;
        IAuthenticate authenticate = new Authenticate();
        AuthResponse twitAuthResponse = authenticate.AuthenticateMe(AuthenticateSettings);

        // Do the timeline
        var utility = new Utility();
        searchJson = utility.RequstJson(SearchSettings.SearchUrl, twitAuthResponse.TokenType, twitAuthResponse.AccessToken);

        return searchJson;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: BTW I'm using Unity to do some dependency injection, the original example used Ninject, but it shouldn't matter, pretty much I'm doing the same thing by registering the interface with the class.  I believe when the controller action is called, it should initialize the OAuthTwitterWrapper parameters like AuthenticateSettings but for some reason that isn't happening....

Comment: So what *is* happening? You've got four different constructors there... are *any* of them being executed? (Stick breakpoints in all of them.) What's being passed to your controller constructor?

Comment: @JonSkeet , none of the constructors are being executed.  The controller should execute the parameterless constructor when I make a call to the Index Action method, correct?

Comment: I'd expect the controller to be *constructed* with an instance - it's the IoC container that should call the constructor. So what's being passed to your controller constructor?

Comment: I mean I'm newing up a new instance of "OAuthTwitterWrapper.OAuthTwitterWrapper" which is the class that would call the parameterless constructor that pulls all the data from the web.config file.  It seems pretty straightforward to me, but I feel like I'm missing something key here.  When I call the index action, the controller is instantiated with the constructor which should instantiate the class I'm working with?

Comment: *Where* do you think you're "newing up a new instance of `OAuthTwitterWrapper`? You're not doing so in any of the code that you've shown. Again, what is being passed into your controller constructor?

Comment: hrmm I think I see what you're saying to some degree but I thought that part of dependency injection, when you build 
private readonly OAuthTwitterWrapper.OAuthTwitterWrapper _oAuthTwitterWrapper;

    public HomeController(OAuthTwitterWrapper.OAuthTwitterWrapper oAuthTwitterWrapper)
    {
        _oAuthTwitterWrapper = oAuthTwitterWrapper;
    }

its the same as IOAuthTwitterWrapper oAuthTwitterWrapper = new OAuthTwitterWrapper();

Comment: No, that's not *at all* the same as you calling the constructor yourself. The point is that the IoC container creates the `OAuthTwitterWrapper` in the most appropriate way - which may be to call the parameterless constructor, or it may be to call a parameterized constructor using other dependencies. But one way or another, your controller is going to be passed a reference... and you *still* haven't said what that is (whether it's null or a non-null reference - if it's non-null, it must have been constructed somehow...)

Comment: I see @JonSkeet , Let me do a bit more reading.  Thanks.  Right now it's non-null, but it doesnt call the parameterless constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet , I "think" I figured it out.  Essentially with IoC containers and multiple constructors, it won't know which constructor to call.  I labeled the default constructor with the attribute "[InjectConstructor]".  Unfortunately I had to make a reference to Unity in my library(couldn't figure out how to avoid this, oh well).

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is having the same issue...

I labeled the default parameterless constructor with

```
namespace OAuthTwitterWrapper
{
public class OAuthTwitterWrapper : IOAuthTwitterWrapper
{
public IAuthenticateSettings AuthenticateSettings { get; set; }
public ITimeLineSettings TimeLineSettings { get; set; }
public ISearchSettings SearchSettings { get; set; }


[InjectConstructor]
public OAuthTwitterWrapper()
{
    string oAuthConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oAuthConsumerKey"];
    string oAuthConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oAuthConsumerSecret"];
    string oAuthUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oAuthUrl"];
    AuthenticateSettings = new AuthenticateSettings { OAuthConsumerKey = oAuthConsumerKey, OAuthConsumerSecret = oAuthConsumerSecret, OAuthUrl = oAuthUrl };
    string screenname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["screenname"];
    string include_rts = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["include_rts"];
    string exclude_replies = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exclude_replies"];
    int count = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["count"]);
    string timelineFormat = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["timelineFormat"];         
    TimeLineSettings = new TimeLineSettings
    {
        ScreenName = screenname,
        IncludeRts = include_rts,
        ExcludeReplies = exclude_replies,
        Count = count,
        TimelineFormat = timelineFormat
    };
    string searchFormat = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["searchFormat"];
    string searchQuery = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["searchQuery"];
    SearchSettings = new SearchSettings
    {
        SearchFormat = searchFormat,
        SearchQuery = searchQuery
    };
```

after making a reference to Unity(my IoC container).

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed somebody had this issue... Default Constructor is never called in my c++ debug build. The magic word "namespace" explained everything (well, not quite everything, I still don't know why default constructor was not called, no problem with other constructors). But the code works now.